# EOFException HaProxy Spring Project

Tags: java, spring, haproxy

I have a cluster of 3 MariaDB servers, each running on a separate VM. I also have another VM running HaProxy which is sitting in front of the 3 servers and communicating with them, no issues there.

I run into an issue when I connect Spring to the HaProxy server. It works for the first request (not all the time), and than it fails with an EOFException. I took a connection string that I used for connecting directly to a database and pointed it to the HaProxy server instead. When I connect directly to the DB Server, everything works as expected. But when I change to use the HaProxy, that's when I get that exception.

This is my connection settings in application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName= org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mariadb://MariaDB:3306/DATABASE?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&maxAllowedPacket=512000
spring.datasource.username= USER
spring.datasource.password= PASSWORD
```

I'm not sure if there are other settings that are needed or if I need to have something else configured.

This is the HaProxy config file:

```
global
    log 127.0.0.1 local0 notice
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    maxconn 4096

defaults
    log global
    retries 2
    timeout connect 3000
    timeout server 5000
    timeout client 5000

listen mysql-cluster
    bind 0.0.0.0:3306
    mode tcp
    option tcpka
    option mysql-check user haproxy_check
    balance roundrobin
    server mysql-1 10.0.1.11:3306 check
    server mysql-2 10.0.1.12:3306 check
    server mysql-3 10.0.1.13:3306 check
```

Comment: I think this question is better suited for Server fault at : http://serverfault.com/ . You may ask the admin to move there if you want.

Comment: Yeah, you might be right about that, I got so used to STO, i forget about the other sites.

Comment: Good luck with the problem!!!